# Nginx GeoIP load balancing with failover

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, http, failover

I am attempting to set up a test Nginx load balanced environment. So far I have sucessfully configured a load balancer `nginx-balancer1` and 3 servers to serve webpages `nginx1, nginx2 & nginx3`.

I want to balance the load by region depending on the visitor's IP. I have configured my Nginx `nginx-balancer1` to use the Maxmind GeoIP Country data.

So here is my configuration to the upstream servers:

```
# Check where the user is coming from
server {
  location / {
    if ($geoip_city_continent_code = "EU") { proxy_pass http://ams1; }
    if ($geoip_city_continent_code = "NA") { proxy_pass http://sfo1; }
    if ($geoip_city_continent_code = "AS") { proxy_pass http://sgp1; }
}
}
# Define upstream servers
upstream ams1 { server server1.example.com; }
upstream sfo1 { server server1.example.com; }
upstream sgp1 { server server1.example.com; }
```

This seems to work well, however if I shutdown nginx on say `ams1 (server1.example.com)` and try to go to the main page I receive a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

What I want to figure out is if a server is down, how can I get `nginx-balancer1` to redirect to another server, either the next closest or the next functioning server.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is  [proxy_next_upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_next_upstream) and [proxy_connect_timeout](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_connect_timeout).  So you'd then do something like:

```
proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500;
proxy_connect_timeout   2;
```

Basically if a failure is detected the backend will be marked as down for x seconds and it will try again. Nginx will try the next entry in the upstream block, so yonce the downed upstream comes back up it should automatically be re-enabled in the upstream pool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sadly it doesn't work with my configuration as I am still seeing 502 errors. These directives should be added inside my `server { location / { #HERE }}` correct?

Comment: correct on the location in your nginx conf. What version of nginx are you on? If your upstream is returning a 502 make sure you're using -->
http_502  (instead of http_500 from my example earlier).

Comment: Yeah I tried with http_502 but it hasn't worked :/ I'm using nginx version: nginx/1.1.19. Here is a pastebin of my 'default' file in sites-available if it helps: http://pastebin.com/mi45hUXU

Comment: I don't have this kind of setup in place on my side so it's kinda hard to make a definitive suggestion for a fix, but might be worth reviewing: http://www.andrewparisio.com/2011/02/how-to-create-reverse-https-failover.html   based on that they seem to show you should specify  max_failes and fail_timeout  per server such as  -->  max_fails=3  fail_timeout=31s;

Comment: So yeah I had a look at the link and attempted to change my configurations to use `max_fails & fail_timeout` but I'm still getting the 502 error. Very strange indeed. I've checked the nginx logs but nothing screams out at me `failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`.